# getopts to get multiple values for same argument

Tags: bash, getopts

I am looking to get multiple values from same argument using getopts. I want to use this script to ssh and run commands on a list of hosts provided through a file.

Usage: `.\ssh.sh -f file_of_hosts.txt -c "Command1" "command2"`

Expected output:

```
ssh userid@server1:command1
ssh userid@server1:command2
ssh userid@server2:commnand1
ssh userid@server2:commnand2
```

Sample Code I used but failed to get expected results

```
id="rm08397"
while getopts ":i:d:s:f:" opt
   do
     case $opt in
        f ) file=$OPTARG;;
        c ) cmd=$OPTARG;;
     esac
done
shift "$(($OPTIND -1))" 
# serv=$(for host in `cat $file`
# do 
#     echo -e "$host#"
# done
# )

# for names in $serv
# do 
#     ssh $id@$serv: 


for hosts in $file;do
   for cmds in $cmd;do
      o1=$id@$hosts $cmds
      echo $o1
   done   
done
```

Comment: `getopts` doesn't support this format directly.

Comment: Going further off-topic, you might want to look at something like Ansible. There are already lots of tools for doing things like this without needing to reimplement them from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @barmar I will look for other options to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect by repeating `-c` :

```
declare -a cmds
id="rm08397"
while getopts ":c:f:" opt
   do
     case $opt in
        f ) file="$OPTARG";;
        c ) cmds+=("$OPTARG");;
     esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1)) 

for host in $(<$file);do
   for cmd in "${cmds[@]}";do
      echo ssh "$id@$host" "$cmd"
   done   
done

# Usage: ./ssh.sh -f file_of_hosts.txt -c "Command1" -c "command2"
```

Comment: Thank you @Philippe. This seems to be working. Appreciate your response